# Meaning of Cauchy integral theorem - the (co)homology viewpoint

Tags: cv.complex-variables, cohomology

I'm not sure what follows is not just a complicated way to deduce a blatant triviality, or if is even correct. Let's try.

In the elementary theory of analytic functions of $1$ complex variable, one proves the classical result:

> **Theorem 1**(Cauchy) Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be a domain (i.e. open connected), $\omega:=fdz\in\Omega^1(U)$ a holomorphic 1-form, and $\gamma\in B_1(U)\subseteq Z_1(U)$ a closed cycle which is a boundary, i.e. it's homologous to 0 in $U$. Then $\langle \omega, \gamma \rangle :=\int_\gamma\omega=0$.

And also a kind of inverse (which I will state in less generality than usual):

> **Theorem 2** (Morera) Let $\omega:=fdz\in \mathcal{A}^{1,0}(U)$ a smooth 1-form of type $(1,0)$. Suppose that for every homologous to zero cycle $\gamma \in B_1(U)$ we have $\langle\omega,\gamma\rangle=0$. Then $\omega\in\Omega^1(U)$, i.e. it's holomorphic (which, in this case, is the same of saying that $\omega$ is $d$-closed where $d=\partial + \bar{\partial}$ is the de Rham differential).

[**Edit:**] The goal of this question is to understand the (co)homological interpretation of the classical Cauchy's and Morera's integral theorems, separating their "topological" content from their "complex analytic" content, perhaps disregarding the "Real Analysis" content (i.e. Morera's theorem could be stated for any *continuous* $f$, not just smooth).

Essentially, Cauchy's theorem states that the 'integral' pairing

$\int: \Omega^1(U)\times Z_1(U)\to \mathbb{C}$

where $\Omega^k$ denotes holomorphic differential k-forms, descends to a pairing involving homology:

$\int:\Omega^1(U)\times H_1(U)\to \mathbb{C}$.

Let $Z^1_{hol}(U)$ and $B^1_{hol}(U)$ be the $\partial$-closed and $\partial$-exact holomorphic 1-forms. One can see that $Z^1_{hol}(U)=\Omega^1(U)$ and $B^1_{hol}(U)=\Omega^1(U)\cap\mathrm{d}\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(U)$. Since exact forms have zero integral on closed loops, the above pairing descends further to:

$H^1(\Gamma(U,\Omega^{\bullet}_U))\times H_1(U)\to\mathbb{C}$.

Now, since $U$ is a Stein manifold, if I'm not mistaken, we have $H^i(\Gamma(U,\Omega^{\bullet}_U))\cong \mathbb{H}^i(\Omega^{\bullet}_{U})$ where the latter is holomorphic de Rham cohomology. And now I think that by Dolbeault/Poincaré lemma $\Omega^{\bullet}_{U}$ is a resolution of the constant sheaf $\mathbb{C}$, so the above hypercohomology is just sheaf cohomology of the sheaf $\mathbb{C}$, which is dual to $H_1(U,\mathbb{C})$, which, by P.D. on non-compact manifolds is in turn dual to de Rham with *compact supports* (and complex coefficients) $H^1_{dR,c}(U)$  [**edit:** added the compact supports thing]. So we get a pairing:

$H^1_{dR\, c}(U)\times H_1(U) \to \mathbb{C}$

that is a map

$PD: H^1_{dR\, c}(U)\to H_1(U,\mathbb{C})^*$

which, were $U$ compact, would just be the Poincaré duality [**edit:** which should be nothing but Poincaré duality for non-compact manifolds].

So my questions:

> 0) Are the above passages correct?

---

> 1) Is it possible to recover Cauchy's theorem (Theorem 1) from some version of Poincaré duality by just doing the above passages in the inverse order? [**edit:** so, it seems the answer is "yes"]

---

> 2) Can we say the map $PD$ defined above is an isomorphism? [**edit:** given 1), the answer is "yes"]

---

> 3) What about Theorem 2? Does it have a cohomological interpretation? Maybe something like:
>   $\forall R, 0=\langle \partial R, \omega\rangle=\langle R, d \omega\rangle$ then $d\omega=0$ ?

Comment: I hope you don't mind; I fixed some of your TeX.

Comment: Do you perhaps want to use cohomology with compact support for (2), btw?  The answer to 0) seems to be "yes."

Comment: @Daniel: I know P.D. would hold with compact supports, but in this case it seems to me that we just get usual cohomology (any supports). Am I missing something?

Comment: @unknowngoogle: There's a pairing in the general case, but it's not guaranteed to be perfect unless there are compact supports. I'm having trouble coming up with a counterexample which is a region in $\mathbb{C}$ though.

Comment: This stuff is ***not*** what I call Cauchy's Theorem and Morera's Theorem (*but perhaps this is just a matter of opinion*). For me, the most interesting part of the theorems is that we don't assume $f$ to be smooth, but smoothness then follows automatically. If you assume smoothness from the start, then what you call Cauchy's and Morera's Theorems are more-or-less immediate consequences of Stoke's Theorem (or Green's Theorem in the plane).

Comment: ....arrgh!! It should be Stokes', not Stoke's...I keep making that mistake!!!

Comment: @Daniel: I think you were actually right, i.e. we actually get de Rham with *compact supports* in my argument: from hypercohomology one gets sheaf cohomology of the constant sheaf $\mathbb{C}$, which is dual to $H_1(U,\mathbb{C})$, which, by P.D. on non-compact manifolds is in turn dual to de Rham with *compact supports* (and complex coefficients) $H^1_{dR,c}(U)$. 

Comment: @Zen Harper: Well, on Rudin's "Real and complex analysis" and in Lang's "Complex analysis", Cauchy's theorem is definitely stated for $f$ *holomorphic* (i.e. $fdz$ a *holomorphic* 1−form). There's 
no reference to less regular functions (apart from the integration path $\gamma$, which is supposed to be continuous, but can be as well assumed to be smooth -or even piecewise polynomial by Weierstrass approximation- staying within the same cohomology class).

Comment: @Zen Harper: On the  other hand, as you remark, Morera's theorem is usually stated in greater generality, i.e. assuming $f$ to be just *continuous* (rather than *smooth*). But my goal in this question was to give a cohomological interpretation of Cauchy's and Morera's theorems, separating their "topological" content from their "complex-analytic" content. If my argument is reliable, Cauchy's theorem boils down to local exactness of holomorphic differential forms (Dolbeault's lemma) and Poincaré duality.

Comment: @Zen: Also, in the case of a domain $U$ in $\mathbb{C}$, I think Stokes theorem is itself an immediate consequence of Poincaré duality (and the fact that $\partial$ on homology is adjoint to $d$ on cohomology), after having proved the topology/analysis result that every continuous path $\gamma$ is homologous to a chain of paths made of 1-manifolds and which is the boundary of a sub-domain of $U$.

Comment: Actually, one version of Stokes' theorem , stated in terms of chains,
is the statement that $\partial$ on the smooth singular chains is the adjoint to $d$ on the DeRham complex with respect to the pairing given by integration. I think this is the one you thinking about.

The manifold version can be interpreted more than one way. Probably
the least Baroque is that it computes the connecting homomorphism
in top dimension for a compact oriented manifold, of the long exact sequence coming from the pair consisting of the manifold and its boundary.

Comment: Its worth noting that for a complex one dimensional manifold $U$,
$\Omega^{1,1}(U)=\Omega^2(U)$. That is every two form is of type $(1,1)$. Hence requiring $\overline{\del}(\alpha)=0$ for a $(1,0)$-form is equivalent to $d\alpha=0$. So in fact your version of Moreira's theorem is Poincare duality decorated with the Dolbeaut decomposition of the De Rham complex. 

Comment: @OP:  As Zen Harper points out, your version of Morera's theorem is far from the most general one; to recover the more general theorem, you might try using distribution-valued forms.

Comment: @Daniel: I'm aware of that, but I was trying to look at the topological content of the theorems involved rather than at the analytic subtleties (even if the latter may be the heart of the theorem). I think currents $T$ can be approximated by smooth forms $\omega$ which lie in the same homology class (once interpreted as currents via integration $\eta\mapsto \int\eta\wedge\omega$), so -maybe- considering smooth forms does not alter the "topological content" of the theorem (however trivial it may be). 

Comment: Yes, of course, I'm an Analyst rather than a Topologist, so my mathematical tastes might well be quite different to yours! As I say, it's just a matter of opinion.

Actually I think it's interesting that two mathematicians can have such different attitudes towards the same theorem; one mathematician's "beautiful theorem" is another mathematician's "tedious technical details", maybe?! (Measure theory also springs to mind...!) [*Note: this comment is for humour purposes only*]